# Problem with send form - routing js in laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, routes

I have problem with send my form, when i'm on the subpage url:

```
www.website.com - form works well
www.website.com/subpage - form works well
www.website.com/subpage/subpage - don't work
```

I have routing:

```
Route::post('apply-send', ['as' => 'apply', 'uses' => 'ApplyController@postSend']);
```

and my js:

```
applySend: function() {
  var $contactForm = $('#apply-form');
  var $input = $('#apply-form input');
  var $submitBtn = $contactForm.find(":submit");
  var $alertPrototype = $('<div class="alert alert-dismissible text-center" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><div>');
  counterTimeForm($contactForm, $input);
  $contactForm.on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $alertInfo = $alertPrototype.clone();
    $alertInfo
      .addClass('alert-info')
      .append('Trwa wysyłanie wiadomości...');
    $submitBtn.replaceWith($alertInfo);
    $.post('apply-send', $(this).serialize())
      .done(function() {
        $alertSuccess = $alertPrototype.clone();
        $alertSuccess
          .addClass('alert-success')
          .append('<strong>Dziękujemy!</strong> Twoja wiadomość została wysłana.');
        $alertInfo.replaceWith($alertSuccess);
        $alertSuccess.after($submitBtn);
        $contactForm.trigger('reset');
      })
      .fail(function() {
        $alertDanger = $alertPrototype.clone();
        $alertDanger
          .addClass('alert-danger')
          .append('Wystapił nieoczekiwany błąd. Zadzwoń lub spróbuj ponownie później.');
        $alertInfo.replaceWith($alertDanger);
      });
    var $closeBtn = $('.alert .close');
  });
},
```

I have problem with this line:

```
$.post('apply-send', $(this).serialize())
```

I do not know how to make the form work on every subpage

Comment: do you see any error messages?

Comment: Show your error messages ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your ajax request just goes to wrong route. So, try to set absolute path:

```
$.post('/apply-send', $(this).serialize())
```

Comment: I did it too, I also changed routing

Comment: then you should check where goes your request and what answers server. and add to your questions more info